# How can I copy directory files into another folder?

Tags: c, file, directory, dirent.h

I need to copy files from a certain directory into another, I'm in the part where I allocate strtok into arrays and which I find very confusing. I have 2562 files to copy. I think I need 2D array but I always get errors. Help...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim);

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *sd;
FILE *source, *target;



int main(){

char *token;

int ctr;
char pathsource[40];
char pathtarget[40];
strcpy(pathsource,"C:\\");
strcpy(pathtarget,"C:\\");
system("pause");

dir = opendir(pathsource);
if(dir){

    while( (sd=readdir(dir)) != NULL ) {


        token = strtok(sd->d_name,"\n");
        printf("%s\n",token);


    }       

    closedir(dir);  

}



return 0;
}
```

by the way, I just removed a little bit from the C:\ \ - that isn't the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows OS, you can use command such `system("copy dir1\\*.txt dir2\\");` for which parameter (command string) can be constructed as you want.

For example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char comstart[] = "copy";
    char pathsource[] = "D:\\testdir\\";
    char copypattern[] = "*.*";
    char pathtarget[] = "D:\\testdir2\\";
    char * command;
    // building command
    command = (char*) malloc(strlen(comstart) + strlen(pathsource) + strlen(copypattern) + strlen(pathtarget) + 3);
    if(!command)
    {
        printf("Unexpected error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(command, comstart);
    strcat(command, " ");
    strcat(command, pathsource);
    strcat(command, copypattern);
    strcat(command, " ");
    strcat(command, pathtarget);
    // command execution
    int res = 0;
    res = system(command);
    if( res == 0)
    {
        printf("Files copied successfully!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unexpected error with code %d!\n", res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or you can use more advanced approach with Win API functions. See:

[CopyFileEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MoveFileEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and other